# When must an eigenvector have only non-negative entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, eigenvector

What would be a reasonable sufficient condition on a real symmetric matrix that would force its eigenvector with largest eigenvalue (or one of its eigenvectors with maximal eigenvalue) to have only non-negative entries?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metzler_matrix

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-matrix_(mathematics)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124645/when-can-a-matrix-with-negative-entries-have-a-completely-non-negative-dominant?rq=1

Comment: I think you're looking for this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0024379518301253

Comment: Name of @wlad's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1067421): [Tarazaga - On the structure of the set of symmetric matrices with the Perron–Frobenius property](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2018.03.015). Other links are [Perron–Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), [Metzler matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metzler_matrix), [Z-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-matrix_(mathematics)), and [When can a matrix with negative entries have a completely non-negative dominant eigenvector?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124645).